# How I combine/merge 2 selectlist to 1 select list and save it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Sorry im newbie, so far i code learn from article and youtube sometimes, but in this situation, i cant find it for answer (maybe i dont understand to implement in my code) can you guys help me with my asp core 2.1 code?

i want in my asp-item viewbag can combine 2 tabel in database,
ie: "Kodeakun" + "Namaakun" and save to database in each table.

in my transaction model

```
public class Transaction
{   [ForeignKey(nameof(ChartAccount))]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Kodeakun { get; set; }
    public string Namaakun { get; set; }
    public ChartAccount ChartAccount { get; set; }
    public string Fullname
    {
        get { return Kodeakun + " - " + Namaakun; }
    }

    public string NoBukti { get; set; }
    public DateTime Tanggal { get; set; }
    public string Deskripsi { get; set; }
    public int Debit { get; set; }
    public int Kredit { get; set; }
}
```

in my transaction controler at insert code

```
// GET: Transactions/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
    ViewData["Id"] = new SelectList(_context.ChartAccounts, "Id","Id");
    return View();
    }


    // POST: Transactions/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Kodeakun,Namaakun,NoBukti,Tanggal,Deskripsi,Debit,Kredit")] Transaction transaction)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(transaction);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["Id"] = new SelectList(_context.ChartAccounts, "Id", "Id", transaction.Id);
        return View(transaction);
    }
```

in my view code

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label">Akun</label>
            <select asp-for="Id" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Id"></select>
        </div>
```

i try but not work

```
ViewData["Id"] = new SelectList(_context.ChartAccounts, "Kodeakun"+"Namaakun","Id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a `SelectList`, just an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Therefore, the easiest solution to the problem is:

```
ViewData["Id"] = _context.ChartAccounts.Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = x.Id.ToString(),
    Text = $"{x.Kodeakun} {x.Namaakun}"
});
```

Obviously, you can format the text however you want.

Comment: Yep, it work, the view has "kodeakun" + "Namaakun", But when I, click button to insert value to database (button create) it return an error. InvalidOperationException: The property 'Id' on entity type 'Transaction' has a temporary value. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.